# Flutter / FireStore : Get the ID of the document just created in Collection

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, document

I am adding data in Firestore with User > Accomodation collection. Firestore is automatically creating a new document in the collection Accomodation with all the details I haved added. But now I need to get the id of the document that he has just created to pass it to another screen. Should I create my own Accomodation ID or is there a way to get it ?

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection('Users')
.doc(uid)
.collection('Accomodation')
.add(data);
```

The User can have multiple Accomodation already created, I need to get the one just created.

Comment: The User have an ID? You can use this ID and then access to the object inside.

Comment: Yes the User has an ID, but he as multiple Accommodation already. I need the latest created.

Comment: This depends on how you create the Acomodation colection in Firestore, but you should create this with Auto Id, so when a new is created already have an ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after adding a document you will get a document reference, with this reference you can get id, i don't know is that method names changed or not after new patches but solution must be similar to that

```
DocumentReference docRef = await 
FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection('Users')
.doc(uid)
.collection('Accomodation')
.add(data);
print(docRef.documentID);
```

Comment: Great, it works, thanks !! Correction : docRef.id